# Converting *.WDP files to PNG/JPEG using ImageMagick in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to find a way to convert *.wdp files to png/jpeg in PowerShell.

On the net, I found open source software called ImageMagick that can process *.wdp files, but the list of [Supported Image Formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) says that I need to download the [jxrlib](https://jxrlib.codeplex.com/)  delegate library and "put the JxrDecApp and JxrEncApp applications in your execution path".

So the question is what does "put the JxrDecApp and JxrEncApp applications in your execution path" mean? How should I use them?

I did my best googling it up, but failed to find an answer. This is why I am here asking you to help me out.

Code examples would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: execution path is anything under the Path environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is telling you that those libraries need to be downloaded and placed in location that your computer knows to look when it attempts to find code to execute.  This location is known as your PATH and is stored in an environment variable named PATH (more info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them))

So you just need to put those library files in any of the locations referenced in PATH, you can see which folders those are by opening up PowerShell and calling the path environment variable like so `$env:PATH`, which will show you a semi-colon seperated list of all locations in your PATH, just place the library files in whichever of them makes sense for you.